# Difference between @ManagedProperty and FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("bean")

Tags: jsf, managed-property, externalcontext

What's the difference between:

```
public class GameController implements Serializable{

@ManagedProperty(value="#{Gamebean}")
private Game game;
```

and

```
public class GameController implements Serializable{

private Game game;

public GameController(){
game =(Game)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("Gamebean");
}
```

and if there's no difference what method is better ?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@ManagedProperty` way will autocreate bean if it doesn't exist yet. The `getSessionMap()` way won't and may thus return `null` if bean isn't (auto)created beforehand.

The code which achieves the same with least effort and concern is better.

Comment: Thank you for responding :D